# Sumar Cast en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Hola amigos quiero hacer una suma de una serie de elementos que **"casteo"** a decimal
, esto es lo que estoy tratando de hacer. Pero me dice

> Incorrect syntax near 'sum'.

```
select sum(  SELECT CAST(em.sueldoDiario AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) )

from
sysCPPuestos p
inner join sysCPCentroCosto cc
on cc.idSysCPEmpresas = p.idSysCPEmpresas
inner join sysCPEmpleados em
on em.idSysCPEmpresas = p.idSysCPEmpresas

where p.idSysCPEmpresas = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no estas usando una subconsulta no pues poner dentro del CAST el `SELECT` por eso es que te esta indicando el error, si lo quitas tu codigo deberia funcionar, espero que te sirva

```
select sum(CAST(em.sueldoDiario AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) )

from
sysCPPuestos p
inner join sysCPCentroCosto cc
on cc.idSysCPEmpresas = p.idSysCPEmpresas
inner join sysCPEmpleados em
on em.idSysCPEmpresas = p.idSysCPEmpresas

where p.idSysCPEmpresas = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente necesitas eliminar el segundo `SELECT`:

```
select sum( CAST(em.sueldoDiario AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) )
from
sysCPPuestos p
inner join sysCPCentroCosto cc
on cc.idSysCPEmpresas = p.idSysCPEmpresas
inner join sysCPEmpleados em
on em.idSysCPEmpresas = p.idSysCPEmpresas
where p.idSysCPEmpresas = 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(em.sueldoDiario AS DECIMAL(18, 4)))
FROM
sysCPPuestos p
inner join sysCPCentroCosto cc
on cc.idSysCPEmpresas = p.idSysCPEmpresas
inner join sysCPEmpleados em
on em.idSysCPEmpresas = p.idSysCPEmpresas

WHERE p.idSysCPEmpresas = 1
```

El **CAST** debe contener al **SUM**.

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!